# Auto populate a node add with values of another node

Tags: 7, nodes

Is there any module that auto-populates the fields of a node/add form with the values of an already existing node? I would like to pass the node ID in the URL and get the form prepopulated with the values taken from that node.

I know it is possible to do; I am just wondering if someone has already done it in a module I could use.

Comment: There is the Prepopulate Module (http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) that might help you along the way with respect to fields, but I'm not aware of any that does it for all of them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for recommendations or suggestions on hosting, books, tools, modules, themes, distributions, tutorials, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean [node clone](http://drupal.org/project/node_clone) module?

> The clone module allows users to make a copy of an existing item of site content (a node) and then edit that copy. The authorship is set to the current user, the menu and url aliases are reset, and the words "Clone of" are inserted into the title to remind you that you are not editing the original content.

Comment: Do you know if this module works fine with field collections?

Comment: As far as I remember, yes, but you need to test it yourself - there are so many add-ons not compatible with each other it's hard to tell what will and what won't work on any given setup.

Comment: Just tested it. It does not work as I expected. It copies the reference for the collection, so if you change a value of a field of the field collection in the new copy, it will also change the value on the old one.

Comment: Consider filing a bug report. It seems it should be easy to fix, so maybe it will get fixed before you will find a better way.